# How to change SSID, preshared key for wifi from wireless router in android 1.6?

Tags: android

I can edit SSID, preshared key for wifi settings in my code but I also have to access wireless router with my code/program and change SSID, preshared key in the wireless router. Can any one please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if that is possible, unless router exposes web-api or some protocol api to manage that. Just to be sure you are not referring to portable wifi hot-spot settings on ur device rite?